# Drag and Reorder of cells in collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created collectionView with n number of cells and added images to those cells. Now i wish to drag and reorder those cells. Kindly explain me about that

Comment: see this http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: I havent used swift .

Comment: see this https://github.com/ra1028/RACollectionViewReorderableTripletLayout

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/63089/cookbook-moving-table-view-cells-with-a-long-press-gesture

Comment: ok i will try them

Comment: Word of advice, the nshint.io link is the one you really want. The others are either not NSCollectionView or are custom implementations. NSCollectionView as of iOS 9.0 has rearrange support built in and if you can use that instead you'll be better off for it.

Comment: @LucasDerraugh : There is no `NSCollectionView` on iOS. Only `UICollectionView`

Comment: @Losiowaty Sorry, `UICollectionView` was what I meant. To reiterate, `UICollectionView` as of iOS 9.0 has rearrange support built in and if you can use that instead you'll be better off for it

Answer (score 0):

This link would help you

[enter link description here](https://github.com/mmick66/KDRearrangeableCollectionViewFlowLayout/blob/master/KDRearrangeableCollectionViewFlowLayout/KDRearrangeableCollectionViewCell.swift)